# Retrofit response failed, Everytime

Tags: android, api, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to understand how retrofit works but every time my response is failed I even used GitHub API but still my response failed, am I doing something wrong I am so confused

I am just trying to get data from api but its failed everytime

```
public class BloggerAPI {

public static final String key = "AIzaSyCUEWi0Cms8TCHECErAUM1cd7Ij2ob-gz4";
public static final String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/6834130421462775039/posts/";

public static PostService postService = null;

public static PostService getService()
{
    if(postService == null)
    {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        postService = retrofit.create(PostService.class);
    }
    return postService;
}

public interface PostService {
    @GET("?key="+key)
    Call<KPBapi> getPostList();
    }

}


 public void getData(){

    Call<KPBapi> blogDataCall = BloggerAPI.getService().getPostList();
    blogDataCall.enqueue(new Callback<KPBapi>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<KPBapi> call, Response<KPBapi> response) {
            KPBapi blogData = response.body();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<KPBapi> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

---

```
public class KPBapi {

@SerializedName("kind")
@Expose
private String kind;
@SerializedName("items")
@Expose
private List<Item> items = null;
@SerializedName("etag")
@Expose
private String etag;

public String getKind() {
    return kind;
}

public void setKind(String kind) {
    this.kind = kind;
}

public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

public String getEtag() {
    return etag;
}

public void setEtag(String etag) {
    this.etag = etag;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `posts/`from url:

```
public static final String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/6834130421462775039/posts/";
```

to

```
public static final String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/6834130421462775039/";
```

and change getPostList() GET to `"posts?key="+key`

Comment: But Artur I think whenever we attache url and key here's we need to put slash (/) in our code. Right?

Comment: in your case, it is creating a path "posts/?key=" this part should be without slash before the question mark

Comment: Bro i know but when we create a base url then we m ust put slash at the end.

Comment: so in getPostList() Get set `posts?key=` and from url remove "posts/"

Comment: Please give me another solution